# macOS Sonoma: Is QuickLook triggered on terminal via `qlmanage` broken for videos?

Tags: macos, quicklook

I'm getting an exception when I want to trigger QuickLook from terminal.app with `qlmanage -p example.mov`

```
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
/.../example.mov
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error: Setting highlightedTimeRanges is not supported in your app.'
```

Doesn't matter what kind of video (mov, mp4, ...). It is working fine with all other formats (images, PDF, spreadsheets, ..) and I believe it was working in previous macOS versions.

Anyone having a hint why qlmanage throws that exception?